# How do I copy files with punctuation in them?

Tags: files, lxde

I had some files (text documents and saved webpages) that I was copying to a usb by selecting them all pressing Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V into the usb drive. As soon as it started copying, a dialogue would pop up saying I had to rename or skip a file. This went on for a lot of the files and I realised if I wanted to copy those files I would have to take out all the punctuation in the files name. I don't know what to do, it seems like I have no choice but to do this for all these files. How do I stop this?

Comment: What kind of punctuation do you have in your file names?

Comment: And what kind of file system is there in the USB drive?

Comment: It's basicly just fullstops, commas that sort of thing. The file system of the key is FAT32.

Comment: Any colons in the filename?

Comment: I suppose so but now that everythings been de-punctuation-ed and that was a while ago....I can only say there must have been in one or two of the file names. Also, the key is new so it's nothing to do with formatting it wrongly in the past or anything.

Comment: How do I mark this question as solved? it seems to have fixed itself somehow. Thanks everyone for the helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following script, assuming you want to copy all the files from a directory DIR1 to another DIR2 on your USB key.

If your file selection is more complicated you can adapt the script e.g. by using `find`.

If you have other illegal characters, just add further `sed` commands.

```
#!/bin/bash 

DIR1=/path/to/origin 
DIR2=/path/to/target 

for file in `ls $DIR1` 
do
   newfile=`echo $file |  sed 's/\./_stop_/g' | sed 's/,/_comma_/g'`
   cp $DIR1/$file $DIR2/$newfile 
done
```

Comment: Does this take the punctuation out as it copies?

Comment: This would copy a file named `,..,` to `_comma__stop__stop__comma_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same file system in the source partition (your internal drive) and the target partition (your USB pendrive), the copying should work, at least if you put quotes around the file names.

But it is a good idea to avoid special characters in file names (and I mean characters with a special meaning in the file systems as well as in shell programs and operating systems that are or will be used).

The following link helps identify which characters that can be used and which characters that should be avoided,

[superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os](https://superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os)

> Summary:
>
> - Windows: anything except ASCII's control characters and `\ / : * ? " < > |`
> - Linux, OS-X: anything except null or /
>
> On all platforms it is best to avoid non-printable characters such as
>   the ASCII control-characters.
>
> In Linux and OS-X only / of the printable ASCII set is prohibited I
>   believe. Some characters (shell metacharacters like `* ? !`) will cause
>   problems in command lines and will require the filename to be
>   appropriately quoted or escaped.